# FOR loop Netezza issue

Tags: loops, procedure, netezza

I'm working with stored procedures in netezza.
I want to loop over a range of values.
The upper bound on the loop is passed as a variable into the sproc by the user.

i.e. EXECUTE SPROC(12);

so problem is that Netezza (aginity workbench) won't accept this input variable as the upper bound on the loop.

i.e.

```
DECLARE 
 x alias as $1.
begin 
   for i in 1..x loop
     ...do stufff... 
    end loop; 
end;
```

I know that this can be solved using loop and exit style loop but It's eating me up as to why i can't do the above given that the documentation suggests that it's possible to do so.

Anyone know why this doesn't work or how to make it work?

Thanks.
Clancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below working example -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE generateTime(integer)
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL RETURNS varchar(255) AS

BEGIN_PROC

DECLARE
        p_abc     integer;
        p_bcd     integer;

        p_var1    ALIAS FOR $1;


BEGIN
        p_bcd := ISNULL(p_var1, 10);

        raise notice 'p_bcd=%',p_bcd;

        FOR p_abc in 0..(p_bcd)
        LOOP
                raise notice 'Hello World %', p_abc;
        END LOOP;
END;


END_PROC;
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Varun. That works. Weird that the official documentation failed to advise to use the parentheses.