# Generating NULL counts by looping over columns in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

I'm trying to query a Netezza table to get count of rows where a column value is NULL -- for all columns. Concretely, assume we have the following table (titled, say, `merchants`)

```
business_name    phone                 email
-------------------------------------------------------
NULL             505-844-1234         john@example.com
Alibaba          NULL                 mary@domain.com
NULL             NULL                 harry@company.com
```

I want to generate an output table like:

```
column_name          NULL_count
-------------------------------
business_name          2
phone                  2
email                  0
```

I can generate it for individual columns using:

```
select count(*)
from merchants
where <column_name> is null;
```

However, my table has over 100 columns and I don't want to hand code the queries. I'm aware that I can write a Java/Python code to query the table programmatically or even write a script to generate ~100 queries. However, the task does not seem overly complicated and I feel it should be achievable in pure SQL. The list of columns for every Netezza table is available via:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE LOWER(table_name) = 'merchants'`
```

I want to run the above `count(*)` query for every column in the above list. I'm having difficulty figuring the proper join and/or using stored procedure. So far, I've tried modifying a Netezza stored procedure as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21870410/for-loop-netezza-issue), but I keep getting syntax errors on the original code listed there.

TL;DR How can I generate null count for all columns in Netezza ?

Answer (score 4):

Code for table shown in question -

```
VARUNDBTEST.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> create table sample(business_name varchar(255), phone varchar(255), email varchar(255));
CREATE TABLE
VARUNDBTEST.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> insert into sample values(NULL,'505-844-1234','john@example.com');
INSERT 0 1
VARUNDBTEST.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> insert into sample values('Alibaba',NULL,'mary@domain.com');
INSERT 0 1
VARUNDBTEST.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> insert into sample values(null,NULL,'harry@company.com');
INSERT 0 1
VARUNDBTEST.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from sample;
 BUSINESS_NAME |    PHONE     |       EMAIL
---------------+--------------+-------------------
 Alibaba       |              | mary@domain.com
               | 505-844-1234 | john@example.com
               |              | harry@company.com
(3 rows)
```

Code for Reference table -

```
                   Table "TBL1"
  Attribute  |          Type          | Modifier | Default Value
-------------+------------------------+----------+---------------
 COLUMN_NAME | CHARACTER VARYING(255) |          |
 NULL_COUNT  | CHARACTER VARYING(255) |          |
Distributed on hash: "COLUMN_NAME"
```

Procedure Code (getNullCount.sql)-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getNullCount()
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL RETURNS REFTABLE(tbl1) AS

BEGIN_PROC

DECLARE
        p_abc     RECORD;
        p_bcd     RECORD;

BEGIN
        FOR p_abc IN
                SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE LOWER(table_name) = 'sample'
        LOOP
                FOR p_bcd IN
                        execute 'SELECT COUNT(*) as col_null_count FROM SAMPLE WHERE '|| p_abc.column_name||' is null'
                LOOP
                        execute immediate 'INSERT INTO '|| REFTABLENAME||' VALUES('||quote_literal(p_abc.column_name)||','|| p_bcd.col_null_count||')';
                END LOOP;

        END LOOP;

return reftable;

END;
END_PROC;
```

Procedure creation and execution -

```
VARUNDBTEST.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> \i getNullCount.sql
CREATE PROCEDURE


VARUNDBTEST.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> call getnullcount();
  COLUMN_NAME  | NULL_COUNT
---------------+------------
 BUSINESS_NAME | 2
 EMAIL         | 0
 PHONE         | 2
(3 rows)
```

Hope this will help.